# Windows.Forms SplitContainer.SplitterWidth will not stay set at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to put a cool little image like this

[image: one of these guys]

For my split container drag button.

I do the following in the OnPaint Event

```
private void splitContainer1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as SplitContainer;            

        e.Graphics.DrawImage("...".Properties.Resources.divider, control.SplitterRectangle, 0, 0, 1040, 50, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    }
```

It does draw the image as I would like, the problem is that the height is ALWAYS 4 pixels.
In the designer I set the SplitterWidth to 15, but at runtime it always stays at 4. So, only 4 pixels actually shows up.

Comment: That seems like an unnecessarily giant splitter image. Why do you need one that's huge? Is this a touch screen application?

Comment: It's not that big in the app, I write it to a rectangle as 15*250. #1. That is the image from the graphic designer, #2, it ensures that nothing is pixelated.

Comment: Unable to reproduce it.  An image I created at 1040 x 50 drew 15 pixels high into my splitter bar just fine.

Comment: @LarsTech Could you try it in a tablepanellayout with dock set to fill?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, according to your comment, having the `SplitterPanel` inside a `TableLayoutPanel` does make the runtime *forget* the `SplitterWidth` setting, so I did duplicate the problem.  `TableLayoutPanels` are weird creatures.

The unfortunately obvious work-around:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  splitContainer1.SplitterWidth = 15;
}
```

Comment: Did that work for you? Because I did that inside my paint method--which now that I think about it is a good deal different than doing it in my constructor.

Comment: Plus, that same line of code is being called in the InitializeComponent() method anyways.

Comment: @JonathanHenson I wouldn't set properties during a paint event.  My line of code *after* `InitializeComponent()` fixed the problem.  If not, you can always move it to the `Form1_Load()` event, too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that when I get home tonight.